# Callback для process.stdout.write?

Tags: node.js

Как убедиться, что запись в поток была полностью завершена?

Вот так?

```
await  process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
```

Comment: к сожалению никак, поток `stdout` немного особенный в nodejs, на разных ОС ведет себя по разному, на посикс подобных ОС метод `write` синхронный, а на виндовс асинхронный + нельзя слушать событие `finish`

Comment: То есть никак нельзя убедиться что я полностью передал строку в поток? Даже зная полный размер строки?

Comment: ты пробовал `stdout.on('finish', cb)` и `stdout.on('end', cb)`?

Comment: Ничего не происходит. У меня ubuntu. 

Делаю так 
  process.stdout.on('end', ()=>{})

Comment: @norbornen `process.stdout and process.stderr differ from other Node.js streams - They will never emit the 'finish' event.`

Comment: @manking, я же вам написал что на убунту метод `write` синхронный)